# Question about the proof of the Trace Theorem from Evan's book of PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm reading the book about PDE's from Evans, and I'm stuck in the proof of the Trace Theorem. (My question is below, after the theorem!)

> **THEOREM 1** (Trace Theorem)**.** Assume $U$ is bounded and $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Then there exists a bounded linear operator $$T : W^{1,p}(U) \rightarrow L^p(\partial U)$$ such that
>
> $\quad$(i) $Tu=u|_{\partial U}$ if $u \in W^{1,p}(U) \cap C(\bar{U})$
>
> and
>
> $\quad$(ii) $$\|Tu\|_{L^p(\partial U)} \le C \| U \|_{W^{1,p} (U)},$$ for each $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$, with the constant $C$ depending only on the $p$ and $U$.
>
> **DEFINITION.** We call $Tu$ the trace of $u$ on $\partial U$.
>
> **Proof.** 1. Assume first $u \in C^1(\bar{U})$. As in the first part of the proof of Theorem 1 in §5.4 let us also intially suppose $x^0 \in \partial U$ and $\partial U$ is flat near $x^0$, lying in the plane $\{x_n=0\}$. Choose an open ball $B$ as in the previous proof and let $\hat{B}$ denote the concentric ball with radius $r/2$.
>
> $\quad$Select $\zeta \in C_c^\infty(B)$, with $\zeta \ge 0$ in $B$, $\zeta \equiv 1$ on $\hat{B}$. Denote by $\Gamma$ that portion of $\partial U$ within $\hat{B}$. Set $x'=(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} = \{x_n=0\}$. Then
> \begin{align}
> \int_\Gamma |u|^p \, dx' &\le \int_{\{x_n=0\}} \zeta |u|^p \, dx' \\
> &= -\int_{B^+} (\zeta |u|^p)_{x_n} \, dx \\
> &= -\int_B^+ |u|^p \zeta_{x_n} + p|u|^{p-1} (\text{sgn} u)u_{x_n} \zeta \, dx \\
> &\le C \int_{B^+} |u|^p + |Du|^p \, dx,
> \end{align}
>
> 2. If $x^0\in\partial U$, but $\partial U$ is not flat near $x^0$, we as usual straighten out the boundary near $x^0$ to obtrain the setting above. Applying estimate (1) and changing variables, we obtain the bound $$\int_{\Gamma}|u|^pdS\le C\int_U|u|^p+ |Du|^pdx,$$ where $\Gamma$ is some open subset of $\partial U$ containing $x^0$.

The proof continues, but in the part 2 he asserts that "Applying estimate (1) and changing variables" the inequality holds. But I do not see that. Maybe I'm using the change of variables in a wrong way. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the proof of Theorem 1 in §5.4? I suppose it is the same change of variable used.

Comment: @ArcticChar I did. I'm also stuck in that theorem because of such change of variable. Is there something simple I am not seeing?

Comment: Can you describe what is the question that you face with that change of variable?

Comment: @ArcticChar We can prove the inequality for $\int_{\Gamma}|u(f(x))|^pdS\le C\int_U|u(f(x))|^p+ |Du(f(x))|^pdx $so to go back to the another variable, we have, using the change of variable theoem, $\int_{\Gamma}|u|^pgdS\le C\int_U|u|^pg+ |Du|^pgdx$ where $g$ is the module of the jacobian of the inverse of $f$. But this is not the inequalite we want, because of the jacobian.